# Why isn't this JOIN working?

Tags: mysql, join

Database Tables

ss_merchant

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| pk_merchant_id | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name           | varchar(45)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| website        | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

ss_merchant_store

```
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| pk_merchant_store_id | bigint(20)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| fk_pk_merchant_id    | bigint(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| street               | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| city                 | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| postcode             | varchar(8)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| telephone            | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email                | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

ss_merchant_store_rating

```
+-----------------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                       | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| pk_merchant_store_rating_id | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| fk_pk_merchant_store_id     | bigint(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| rating                      | int(1)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and my query:

```
SELECT *  
FROM ss_merchant 
JOIN ss_merchant_stores 
ON ss_merchant.pk_merchant_id = ss_merchant_stores.fk_pk_merchant_id 
JOIN ss_merchant_store_rating 
ON ss_merchant_stores.pk_merchant_store_id = ss_merchant_store_rating.fk_pk_merchant_store_id
```

Comment: Is your table called ss_merchant_stores or ss_merchant_store ?

Comment: What do you mean with "is not working"? do you obtain an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything specifically wrong with your join but it does make the assumption that all three tables have at least one row for each `merchant_id`.  If you want to allow for non-existant merchant_store_rating rows consider using a [LEFT JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

> If there is no matching row for the
>   right table in the ON or USING part in
>   a LEFT JOIN, a row with all columns
>   set to NULL is used for the right
>   table. You can use this fact to find
>   rows in a table that have no
>   counterpart in another table:

```
SELECT left_tbl.*   FROM left_tbl LEFT JOIN right_tbl 
ON left_tbl.id = right_tbl.id   WHERE right_tbl.id IS NULL;
```

> This example finds all rows in
>   left_tbl with an id value that is not
>   present in right_tbl (that is, all
>   rows in left_tbl with no corresponding
>   row in right_tbl). This assumes that
>   right_tbl.id is declared NOT NULL.